# Tell Mutt to attach files (listed in file)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mutt, slackware

I'm doing my first steps with Mutt (with msmtp in Slackware 13.1).

I'm already able to send mail with attachments like so:

```
cat mail.txt | mutt -a "/date.log" -a "/report.sh" -s "subject of message" -- myself@gmail.com
```

I would like to define the files to be attached in another file and then tell Mutt to read it, something like this:

```
mutt -? listoffilestoattach.txt
```

Is it possible? Or there are similar approaches?

Answer (score 1):

You can populate an array with the list of file names fairly easily, then use that as the argument to `-a`.

```
while IFS= read -r attachment; do
    attachments+=( "$attachment" )
done < listoffilestoattach.txt
for f in ../*.log; do
    attachments+=("$f")
done

mutt -s "subject of message" -a "${attachments[@]}" -- myself@gmail.com < mail.txt
```

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can replace the `while` loop with the (slightly) more interactive-friendly `readarray` command:

```
readarray -t attachments < listoffilestoattach.txt
```

---

If, as appears to be the case, `mutt` requires a single file per `-a` option, then you'll need something slightly different:

```
while IFS= read -r attachment; do
    attachments+=( -a "$attachment" )
done < listoffilestoattach.txt
for f in ../*.log; do
    attachments+=( -a "$f")
done

mutt -s "subject of message" "${attachments[@]}" -- myself@gmail.com < mail.txt
```

Using `readarray`, try

```
readarray -t attachments < listoffilestoattach.txt
attachments+=( ../*.log )
for a in "${attachements[@]}"; do
    attach_args+=(-a "$a")
done
mutt -s "subject of message" "${attach_args[@]}" -- myself@gmail.com < mail.txt
```

Comment: How do I put ls ../*.log inside attachments?

Comment: `attachments+=( ../*.log )`

Comment: Does not work @chepner. Only one file is appended and the rest of files some way goes as destination of the e-mail.

Comment: I'm seeing conflicting man pages about whether `-a` can take multiple arguments or not. Try `attachments+=(-a "$attachment")`, and remove the `-a` from the mutt command line. (http://www.mutt.org/doc/man_page.html says one file only, so that's probably definitive.)

Comment: This way it correctly send to the destination (files are not being appended as destination). But there is only one file appended. I'm doing this: attachment+=(../*.log)
attachments+=(-a "$attachment"), is it correct?