# Append something to each element of the list

Tags: bash

I have a list of files (to be e-mailed). I need to append "-a" to each element of the list (this is a mutt requirement).

I tried this:

```
attachment+=(../*.log) 
attachments+=(-a "${attachment[@]}" )
```

But echo shows -a is append only one time (at the beginning). How do a I get a result like the following?

-a file1.log -a file2.log -a file3.log ...

This question appeared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782416/tell-mutt-to-attach-files-listed-in-file/33782939#33782939).

Comment: Well, that's the point, how?

Comment: So you don't know how to loop over elements of an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapfile` command available in BASH 4 with `printf`:

```
mapfile -t attachments < <(printf -- '-a %s\n' "${attachment[@]}")
```

`printf` will add `-a` before each array element in `attachment` array.

This is assuming there are no newlines in your filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mutt $(ls ../*.log|while read f;do echo -a \"$f\";done) ...
```

To explain, per jpaugh's comment:

When `ls` is used in a pipeline `|` (rather than alone), it puts one file per line (rather than making a table).

`while read <var>;do ... done` is a standard shell pattern for reading single lines from the input (into var).

Putting `"` around the filename `$f` protects against files/paths with spaces in the name.

Finally, the `$(...)` (replacement for the old deprecated backtick ` operator) puts all command output back into a flat list (single line).

Comment: You could enhance this question a lot by explaining what each part does.

Comment: Parsing `ls` output... Wow.